# Verifying personal.sign signature with pyethereum

Tags: metamask, signature, pyethereum

I'm trying to verify a signed message from Metamask with pyethereum.  I can not seem to recover the correct address from the signature.  Lack of documentation isn't helping matters.

On the client side, I have metamask signing with `web3.personal.sign()`.

```
var signer = web3.eth.defaultAccount || web3.eth.accounts[0];
var original_message = "I am but a stack exchange post";
var message = "0x" + original_message.toHex();
var message_hash = web3.sha3('\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n' + message.length.toString() + message);
var signature;
web3.personal.sign(message, signer, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    signature = res;
    console.log({
        "signer": signer,
        "message": message,
        "message_hash": message_hash,
        "signature": signature,
    })
});

{
    message: "0x4920616d20627574206120737461636b2065786368616e676520706f7374"
    message_hash: "0x1a0126ceafb4579293016a4cc3ca0ec753c7d497cda8b3e6ece095c832d92590"
    signature: "0x0cf7e2e1cbaf249175b8e004118a182eb378a0b78a7a741e72a0a34e970b59194aa4d9419352d181a4d1827abbad279ad4f5a7b60da5751b82fec4dde6f380a51b"
    signer: "0x9283099a29556fcf8fff5b2cea2d4f67cb7a7a8b"
}
```

Then I send the signature, hash of the message, and the address to the backend, where I have something like this:

```
>>> from ethereum.utils import ecrecover_to_pub, sha3
>>> from eth_utils.hexidecimal import encode_hex, decode_hex, add_0x_prefix
>>> signer = "0x9283099a29556fcf8fff5b2cea2d4f67cb7a7a8b"
>>> message_hash = "0x1a0126ceafb4579293016a4cc3ca0ec753c7d497cda8b3e6ece095c832d92590"
>>> signature = "0x0cf7e2e1cbaf249175b8e004118a182eb378a0b78a7a741e72a0a34e970b59194aa4d9419352d181a4d1827abbad279ad4f5a7b60da5751b82fec4dde6f380a51b"
>>> 
>>> r = int(signature[0:66], 16)
>>> s = int(add_0x_prefix(signature[66:130]), 16)
>>> v = int(add_0x_prefix(signature[130:132]), 16)
>>> if v not in (27,28):
...     v += 27
... 
>>> pubkey = ecrecover_to_pub(decode_hex(message_hash), v, r, s)
>>> assert(encode_hex(sha3(pubkey)[-20:]) == signer)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

I've tried a few ways to mess around with encoding, but I think I'm still missing something(hopefully obvious).  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you prepend the message with the prefix before signing it? Prefix here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign

Comment: @carver web3js automatically handles that.  "This data is before UTF-8 HEX decoded and enveloped as follows"

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. What I meant was, when you regenerated the hash of the message before recovery, did you include the prefix? This looks like maybe not: `web3.sha3(message)`. You can use https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#hashmessage which abstracts away the prefix. (Also, web3.py will be coming out with native tools for this, soon)

Comment: Also, `message_hash.encode('utf-8')` looks wrong because it's a hex encoded string. You probably want something like `codecs.decode(message_hash[2:], 'hex')`. You may like `eth_utils.decode_hex(message_hash)` better, if you're open to a dependency on `ethereum-utils`.

Comment: If you post the original message, we can verify the prefix.

Comment: @carver This is all great information, thanks.  I've updated my post with your corrections.  However, I'm still seeing the issue.  If you have any other ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in Python looks correct. The message hash in JavaScript is being generated incorrectly.

### Preparing the Message Hash in Javascript

The message hash must be generated using the original message, without hex-encoding it first.

In practice, that means replacing this JavaScript:

```
var message = "0x" + original_message.toHex();
var message_hash = web3.sha3(
  '\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n' +
  message.length.toString() +
  message
);
```

with this:

```
var message_hash = web3.sha3(
  '\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n' +
  original_message.length.toString() +
  original_message
);
```

That will give you the message hash: `0x6e099d83ea72d1ef62e39a501fe000c1458ba5a511510a0e9348b0dfeb298803`

When you use that message hash, you will recover the correct signer: `0x9283099a29556fcf8fff5b2cea2d4f67cb7a7a8b`

**An even better solution: [`hashMessage()`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#hashmessage)**

With web3.js v1, you can call:
`message_hash = web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage("I am but a stack exchange post")`.

*V1 is in Beta, as of October 2017*

---

### Another Common Mistake

*(from an earlier draft of the question)*

**Leaving out the prefix when hashing the message for recovery.**

Because `web3.personal.sign()` adds the prefix for you, it's easy to forget the prefix when hashing the message for recovery. The best solution is again to use web3.js v1 for `web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage()`.

---

### The Simplest Option

As of Web3.py v4, there is built-in support to [recover the message signer](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#web3.eth.account.Account.recoverMessage), like:

```
from web3.auto import w3

# If you have the original message, you need to hash it first
from eth_account.messages import defunct_hash_message
message_hash = defunct_hash_message(text=original_message)

# If you begin with the message hash, start here:
signer = w3.eth.account.recoverHash(message_hash, signature=signature)
```

*Why is it called `defunct_hash_message`?* -- Unfortunately, the message standard is not well supported. It has slightly different implementations in a number of nodes and hardware clients. There are some new message formats that are under discussion and will hopefully gain broader, more consistent adoption soon. For now, Web3.py only explicitly supports the geth-style message format, using the `defunct_hash_message` method.

Comment: 2 potential problems I'm running into.  `web3.personal.sign` requires the message to be hex encoded(`HookedWalletSubprovider - validateMessage - message was not encoded as hex.`), which is why I was adding `0x` and converting the message to hex.  Or well, at least metamask requires it.  Also, `web3.eth.accounts.hashMessage` is not yet widely available, but I look forward to it.  Thanks for all the info.

Comment: Adding: you do accurately get to my problem.  Changing the call to `web3.personal.sign("0x" + message.toHex()...` and just using the plain message when hashing works great.  Thanks again!